# How to trigger GetTripNotifications

Tags: postman, asp.net-core-webapi, trimble-maps

hi I have been working on API for the Get Trip Notifications ([https://tripinsight.alk.com/service.svc/trip/{tripId}/events](https://tripinsight.alk.com/service.svc/trip/%7BtripId%7D/events)).

I have created trip and changed the API's as below to trigger the notifications.

1. Create a short Trip
2. Update Trip Status using TripId
3. Update Stop Status using TripId
4. Update Positions using TripId
5. Check Trip Notification API

Answer (score 0):

Notifications are set at the API key level when it is licensed.

Notifications are triggered by "events" during your trip. For example, a stop event is created whenever there is an update of a stop status to “Arrived” or “Departed”. As another example, an Out of Route (OoR) mileage event is generated when the total mileage of a trip marked as complete differs from the originally planned mileage of the trip by a certain threshold. (That threshold is among the settings chosen when the API key is licensed.)

Notifications are a polling service. You have to ask for them by calling either the GET [Trip Notifications](https://developer.trimblemaps.com/restful-apis/trip-management/trip-notifications/) endpoint or the more general [Event Notifications service](https://developer.trimblemaps.com/restful-apis/trip-management/event-notifications/).